# I have 8 CPU cores and 8 unicorn workers -- why aren't requests being handled concurrently?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unicorn

It's my understanding that the incoming requests should be processed concurrently by default, when I have as many workers as I do cores.  Why am I seeing requests only handled synchronously?

Here's my unicorn.rb:

worker_processes 10

```
APP_PATH = "/var/www/myapp/current" # available in 0.94.0+
APP_PATH_SHARED = "/var/www/myapp/shared"
working_directory APP_PATH
# listen on both a Unix domain socket and a TCP port,
# we use a shorter backlog for quicker failover when busy
listen "/tmp/.sock", :backlog => 64
listen 8080, :tcp_nopush => true

# nuke workers after 30 seconds instead of 60 seconds (the default)
timeout 60

# feel free to point this anywhere accessible on the filesystem
pid APP_PATH_SHARED + "/pids/unicorn.pid"

# By default, the Unicorn logger will write to stderr.
# Additionally, ome applications/frameworks log to stderr or stdout,
# so prevent them from going to /dev/null when daemonized here:
stderr_path APP_PATH_SHARED + "/log/unicorn.stderr.log"
stdout_path APP_PATH_SHARED + "/log/unicorn.stdout.log"



# combine Ruby 2.0.0dev or REE with "preload_app true" for memory savings
# http://rubyenterpriseedition.com/faq.html#adapt_apps_for_cow
preload_app true
GC.respond_to?(:copy_on_write_friendly=) and
  GC.copy_on_write_friendly = true

before_exec do |server|
  ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] = "/var/www/myapp/current/Gemfile"
end

before_fork do |server, worker|
  # the following is highly recomended for Rails + "preload_app true"
  # as there's no need for the master process to hold a connection
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!


   # Before forking, kill the master process that belongs to the .oldbin PID.
  # This enables 0 downtime deploys.
  old_pid = APP_PATH_SHARED + "/pids/unicorn.pid.oldbin"
  if File.exists?(old_pid) && server.pid != old_pid
    begin
      Process.kill("QUIT", File.read(old_pid).to_i)
    rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
      # someone else did our job for us
    end
  end

end

after_fork do |server, worker|

  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) and
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection

end
```

This has been bothering me for many weeks!  Thank you.

Comment: Can you post some output that is demonstrating the requests being processed synchronously instead of concurrently?

Comment: Are you running in production?

Comment: Whats the ruby version you're using?

Comment: MRI, RUBINIUS, JRUBY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're seeing requests only handled synchronously, is because you don't have a thread based server and probably also ruby version.

If you want pure concurrency you wont get it through Unicorn. Unicorn works with process forks not threads. 
If you want that kind of concurrency you should have threadsafe code and use Jruby or rubinius with PUMA.

Puma is a web server that really implements thread based concurrency, but for achieve that you have to use a ruby version that implement thread concurrency to. If not, you'll be forking processes again and i think that way you'll not gain anything with puma instead of Unicorn.

This is have a nice explanation about concurrency in ruby: http://merbist.com/2011/02/22/concurrency-in-ruby-explained/

Then check the puma server and you'll understand what i'm trying to explain: http://puma.io/